# Getting latest version of software with/without Sourceforge

Tags: software-installation, package-management

I want the latest version of software/programs that I have installed on my computer. I figured the best way to do this would be to download the latest one from SourceForge directly rather than via Software Manager.

#### Questions

a) I was hoping there would be a way that I could simply add the link from SourceForge to the Software Manager (similar to how its done with PPAs) and that way you'd always have the latest version installed every time you do `apt update/upgrade`. Is there a way to do that?

b) If not, is the only way to get the latest version to use github/git (how exactly do I do this btw? Even a link to a well-answered previous question would be helpful as some I found to be contradicting) and add whatever PPAs I can find to the Software Manager?

c) Also, let's say I still want the version on SourceForge, can I simply create my own PPA and upload the latest versions on there so I can install them later with Software Manager?

**Old Version of Question [ignore; left for reference]**

When I download and install a software program from Sourceforge, how can I ensure that version remains the latest one? For example, when I install programs via Software Manager, update manager always updates it to the latest version. How would it be able to tell what the latest version of a program installed from Sourceforge is unless I manually visit the Sourceforge site every day and check? (Installing them by downloading their tar.gz packages btw).

Just to clarify, I'm willing to use github (if that applies here?) or whatever other method apart from checking the Sourceforge page myself every time (because that would involve me uninstalling the program and then reinstalling every time an update comes).

I'm on Linux Mint 17.2 if that matters.

Comment: This is what RSS is for...

Comment: What is the problem with a software package manager?

Comment: Removed a bunch of comments about RSS that got...let's say "snippy"

Comment: Thanks all; I rewrote the question so that it's [hopefully!] clearer.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you'll need to check manually if an update is available and, if you want it, manually uninstall the old version and download + install the new one.

It's clearly more cumbersome a process than installing packages via `apt-get`, which also allows you to easily solve dependencies and do updates.  However, there are a few advantages:

- You can compile with your preferred configuration options
- You can get not only the latest version but also any other version you choose, from the latest alpha to the more obsolete (DEB packages offer only one version that you can install, and it's not always the most up-to-date)
- Since you build the program from source, you can modify it if you feel soinclined

Comment: Thanks for the help; would you mind looking at the new question (b and c, specifically) as I guess I'm gonna have to give up on my SourceForge dream lol...

Comment: _"You always get the latest version"_ - depends on whether the application requirements are met on OP's system. Some apps may need e.g. libX version Y as a minimum requirement and if that version is not available in the repos things get complicated...